# Excel IF Text AND Less than Statement, then "Allowed" or "Not Allowed

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

[image]

Hi everyone, I'm having trouble trying to write out a IF statement for excel.

If cell F2 = Error and IF C2-E2 < 0.01 then show "Allowed" but
If cell F2 = Error and IF C2-E2 > 0.01 then show "Not Allowed"

If cell F2 is blank then do nothing

Comment: =IF(F2="Error",IF((C2-E2)<0.01,"Allowed","Not allowed"),"")

Comment: "Expected Value
(Manual Entry)"
 $1,215,000.00
..............
"Grand Total
without Rounding
(Auto Entry)"
1,272,749.9978
..............
Auto Check
 Error 
..............
If Off By A Penny
 Allowed
..............
What I'm seeing when I increase the value and it is more than 0.01 it is still showing allowed? am I missing an additional step?

Comment: You wrote C2-E2<0.01 . 1215000-1272749.9978 = -57750 which is <0.01. I guess you want ABS(C2-E2)<0.01 , so =IF(F2="Error",IF(ABS(C2-E2)<0.01,"Allowed","Not allowed"),"")

Comment: I think like I may need to use two separate cells for the conditioning. The crux of the formula is that if it deviates MORE than 0.01 more or less than the original than it is NOT allowed. So by using two cells (one for more than 0.01 and one for less than 0.01. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Check the `ABS` of the difference.

Comment: @Lowell Try formula with ABS: =IF(F2="Error",IF(ABS(C2-E2)<0.01,"Allowed","Not allowed"),"")

Comment: Oooh I see, I didn't know that ABS was a function in excel. Thank you so much for the guidance. That worked great!!

Comment: @user11222393 `<=` since a penny is allowed.

Comment: @VBasic2008 you are right. Didn't even saw that "penny" meaning in question at first sight. Just took first OP's condition C2-E2 < 0.01 :)

Comment: Very much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(
    AND(ISERROR(F2), C2 - E2 < 0.01),
    "Allowed",
    IF(
        AND(
            ISERROR(F2),
            C2 - E2 >= 0.01
        ),
        "Not Allowed",
        ""
    )
)
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.